# Set inner row column borders of a html table as light grey

Tags: html, css

I have a html table with rows and columns, at the moment the rows and columns don't have any lines so you can't easily distinguish between the data cells.

How can I put a light grey line for each row and columnns using CSS?  I want to be able to style the table border seperately if possible also.

**This will actually be for a newsletter if that matters.**

Answer (score 4):

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
table {
    border: 3px outset #cccccc;
    /* the following is OPTIONAL, try it to see if it's an effect you want */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Make them more specific (IDs, classes) if needed, but that's basically all you need.

Comment: and make them inline, because it's going to be in an email newsletter (td style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;")